# Break Colors Into Even Splits

Tags: r, colors

Suppose I have this data in R:

```
heights = rnorm(1000, 150, 10)

deciles = quantile(heights, probs = seq(.1, .9, by = .1))

     10%      20%      30%      40%      50%      60%      70%      80%      90% 
137.8206 142.2595 145.4719 147.6242 149.8734 152.1049 154.9373 158.6607 163.1900
```

I want to assign a color to each of these heights. I want to make it in such a way, such that all observations between 0 - 137.8206 are light color, all observations between 137.8206 - 142.2595 are a slightly darker color .... and all observations between 158.6607 - 163.1900 are the darkest color. For example, 0 - 137.8206 are a very light shade of red and 158.6607 - 163.1900 are a very dark shade of red.

I was thinking of manually trying to find the min and max range of a red color, and then trying to manually create these breaks - but I think there is a chance I might make a mistake doing this and was looking for a more automatic way of doing this. In the end, I would like a data frame that looks something like this:

```
    height   color
1 148.5791 #FF0000
2 136.1866 #FF4500
3 155.2477 #FF0000
```

- Is there an easier way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the `cut` function with the `breaks` arguments defining your levels for the color changes. The result of this can then be used as an index to select your desired colors.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(heights = rnorm(1000, 150, 10))

(deciles = quantile(df$heights, probs = seq(.1, .9, by = .1)))

breaks <- c(-Inf, deciles["10%"], deciles["80%"], Inf)
COLS <- c("pink", "red", "red4")
df$color <- COLS[cut(df$heights, breaks = breaks)]
head(df)

plot(df$heights, col = df$color, pch = ".", cex = 5)
```

[image]

#### Edit

And here is a further example using a specified number of color levels (`nlev`), which are evenly spaced. I have commented out the red color option in favor of another that better shows the color breaks:

```
nlev <- 10
breaks <- seq(from = min(df$heights), to = max(df$heights), length.out = nlev+1)
# pal <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("pink", "red4"))
pal <- colorRampPalette(colors = c(4,5,7,2))
COLS <- pal(nlev)
df$color <- COLS[cut(df$heights, breaks = breaks)]
plot(df$heights, col = df$color, pch = ".", cex = 5)
abline(h = breaks, lty = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: @ Marc in the box: thank you for your answer! Is there a way to add more colors to this automatically? Instead of just c("pink", "red", "red4") ... is there a way to add maybe 10 colors without specifying them manually, but each of them is a different shade of red? thank you so much!

Comment: @antonoyaro8 - Thanks. I have added another example that hopefully helps you with this.

Comment: @ Marc in the box: Thank you so much for this edit! In this edit, the colors are from blue to red - is it possible for the colors just to be different shades of a single color (e.g. red)? thank you so much!

Comment: Of course. You just need to change the vector of colors in colorRampPalette. The alternative red color palette version is commented out.

Comment: thank you! what do you mean by "commented out"? thanks!

Comment: In R everything after a '#' symbol are comments and not evaluated

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R way with functions [`colorRamp`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/colorRamp.html) and [`rgb`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/rgb.html).

1. create a deciles vector including the extremes 0 and 1 in the vector;
2. find out where in the deciles vector are the heights;
3. create a colors interpolation function with `colorRamp`;
4. pass the shades, scaled to the interval [0, 1] to this function, the output is a RGB matrix;
5. transform the RGB levels into hex codes with function `rgb`.

```r
set.seed(2022)
heights <- rnorm(1000, 150, 10)
deciles <- quantile(heights, probs = (0:10)/10)
range(heights)
#> [1] 115.2477 187.6519

shades <- findInterval(heights, deciles)

colors_fun <- colorRamp(c("white", "red", "darkred"))
rgb_matrix <- colors_fun(shades/max(shades))
head(rgb_matrix)
#>          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,] 181.1818   0.00000   0.00000
#> [2,] 255.0000 162.27273 162.27273
#> [3,] 255.0000 162.27273 162.27273
#> [4,] 255.0000 208.63636 208.63636
#> [5,] 255.0000  69.54545  69.54545
#> [6,] 255.0000 208.63636 208.63636

clrs <- rgb(rgb_matrix, max = 255)

plot(1:1000, heights, col = clrs, pch = 16, cex = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

So to create the data.frame, assign the hex codes returned by `rgb` to their column.

```r
df_colors <- data.frame(height = heights, color = clrs)
head(df_colors)
#>     height   color
#> 1 159.5668 #B50000
#> 2 134.2518 #FFD0D0
#> 3 151.9641 #F40000
#> 4 153.9582 #DF0000
#> 5 159.8854 #B50000
#> 6 154.7081 #DF0000
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

## Edit

Though not asked, to have an alpha channel, use `colorRamp` argument `alpha`.

```r
colors_alpha_fun <- colorRamp(c("white", "red", "darkred"), alpha = TRUE)
rgb_alpha_matrix <- colors_alpha_fun(shades/max(shades))

# transparency set to half the maximum
rgb_alpha_matrix[, 4] <- floor(255*0.5)
head(rgb_alpha_matrix)
#>          [,1]      [,2]      [,3] [,4]
#> [1,] 181.1818   0.00000   0.00000  127
#> [2,] 255.0000 162.27273 162.27273  127
#> [3,] 255.0000 162.27273 162.27273  127
#> [4,] 255.0000 208.63636 208.63636  127
#> [5,] 255.0000  69.54545  69.54545  127
#> [6,] 255.0000 208.63636 208.63636  127

clrs_alpha <- rgb(
  red = rgb_alpha_matrix[,1],
  green = rgb_alpha_matrix[,2],
  blue = rgb_alpha_matrix[,3],
  alpha = rgb_alpha_matrix[,4],
  max = 255
)

plot(1:1000, heights, col = clrs_alpha, pch = 16, cex = 2)
```

[image]

```r
df_colors_alpha <- data.frame(height = heights, color = clrs_alpha)
head(df_colors_alpha)
#>     height     color
#> 1 159.0014 #B500007F
#> 2 138.2665 #FFA2A27F
#> 3 141.0251 #FFA2A27F
#> 4 135.5550 #FFD0D07F
#> 5 146.6899 #FF45457F
#> 6 120.9937 #FFD0D07F
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>